# System.CalloutException: Callout loop not allowed when doing callout from Scheduled Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, scheduled-apex, invocable-method

I am currently having an issue where my Callouts are returning an error:

```
System.CalloutException: Callout loop not allowed
```

The way the system works is this:

1. I have a scheduled job that runs every day, which executes some anonymous code. The code is as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
Flow.Interview.FlowName myFlow = new Flow.Interview.FlowName (params);
myFlow.start();
```

2. Inside the `FlowName` flow, I do some Assignments, make some decisions, and get some records. Eventually, it can reach a path where I do several Apex actions that all call different invocable methods.
3. Each of the invocable methods are fairly simple (they are `Future` methods that make a POST request to an external server and don't do anything with the responses). Each of the invocable methods have also been tested in their own flows and they work fine. But when the scheduled job executes and the invocables are run, I get the above error about callout loops.

Any ideas here? Thank you!